# and operator with random

Tags: python-3.x, logical-operators

i dont understand why the code bellow doesnt work properly. If both variables a and b < 0 it should print that both numbers are negative,else the last message. But it just dont work so, what am i doing wrong? please help!

```
import random
while True:
    input()
    a=random.randint(-9,9)
    b=random.randint(-9,9)
    print(a,b)
    if a and b < 0:
        print("2 negative numbers:",a,b)
    else:
        print("one or both of the numbers are positive!")
```

I'm running this on python 3.4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating Both Operands will resolve the issue. Here both Operands are expressions which results in true or false, so if both result in true; you will get your required result.

```
if ((a < 0) and (b < 0)):
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Although this may be helpful for the question, the answer is not following the expected format for this site. I would recommend you to provide more information on why this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a little confused about how operators distribute.

When you have

```
if a and b < 0
```

it doesn't mean

```
if (both a and b) < 0
```

but instead

```
if (a) and (b < 0)
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (a != 0) and (b < 0)
```

since "numeric zero of all types ... evaluates to false" (see [the reference on booleans on docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#booleans))

---

Instead, you want

```
if a < 0 and b < 0
```

which will tell you if both `a` and `b` are less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating just `a`, not it's relation to `0`:

```
if a < 0 and b < 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
a and b < 0:
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
(a) and (b < 0):
```

`(a)` is `False` when `a` equals `0` and `True` otherwise. Therefore, due to short-circuiting `b < 0` isn't even evaluated.

As a fix you may use `all` method:

```
all(i < 0 for i in (a, b))
```